# push a row to array throgh foreach

Tags: php, arrays

now i do something for my website.
i have an array and use foreach loop to fetch it, i want when end of key, value will push into array
example:

> ```
>  foreach($arr as $key => $value){
>  $resulset = $model->getResultset($value);
>   foreach($resultset as $k => $v){
>    $k will increase from 0-5 or 0-3 depends on result set return it will loop through arr
>
>   }    }
> ```

and i want to push value from result set inside loop to array

but it give me result

```
array(
 array(
  [0] => a
  )
array(
  [0] => b
  )
...
)
```

what i want is

```
array (
 array (
   [0] => a,
   [1]=> b

 
 )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this going? Seeing your attempts will better enable us to assist! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_split` to split characters of a string into an array.

```
<?php

$arr = ['012345', '012345', '012', '012', '0123', '0123'];

$output = array_map('str_split', $arr);

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you but it nó my idea

Comment: My $key incre from 0-5 for 1 resultset and 0-3 for other result set and i need push value of key 0-5 to 1 array and 0-3 to other array

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php 
$arr = array('012345','012345','012','012','0123','0123');
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    $number_array = str_split($v);
    $out[] = $number_array;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($out); exit;
```

Comment: My idea is 
My $key incre from 0-5 for 1 resultset and 0-3 for other result set and i need push value of key 0-5 to 1 array and 0-3 to other array